# Best Way To Get All Dates Between DateA and DateB

Tags: asp.net, css, date

I am using an asp:Calander and I have an object that has a beginning date and an ending date. I need to get all the dates between these two dates and place them in an array so i can then render corresponding dates on the calander with different CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I voted up AlbertEin because he gave a good answer, but do you really need a collection to hold all the dates?  When you are rendering the day, couldn't you just check if the date is withing the specified range, and then render it differently, no need for a collection.  Here's some code to demonstrate

```
DateTime RangeStartDate,RangeEndDate; //Init as necessary
DateTime CalendarStartDate,CalendarEndDate; //Init as necessary
DateTime CurrentDate = CalendarStartDate;

String CSSClass;

while (CurrentDate != CalendarEndDate)
{
    if(CurrentDate >= RangeStartDate && CurrentDate <= RangeEndDate)
    {
        CSSClass= "InRange";
    }     
    else
    {
        CSSClass = "OutOfRange";
    }
    //Code For rendering calendar goes here
    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays (1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime startDate;
DateTime endDate;

DateTime currentDate = startDate;
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime> ();

while (true)
{
    dates.Add (currentDate);
    if (currentDate.Equals (endDate)) break;
    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays (1);
}
```

It assumes that startDate < than endDate, you get the results on the "dates" list

Comment: I know in VB.NET AddDays returns a date object that needs to be assigned. It would be used like this "currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1). I'm not sure if that's the same in C# though.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> RangeDays(DateTime RangeStart, DateTime RangeEnd) {
   DateTime EndDate = RangeEnd.Date;

   for (DateTime WorkDate = RangeStart.Date; WorkDate <= EndDate; WorkDate = WorkDate.AddDays(1)) {
      yield return WorkDate;
   }

   yield break;
}
```

Untested code... but should work.

Comment: i don't know about asp.net calendar but it works great to get the dates between start date and date considering end date is always greater than start date.

Answer (score 1):

```
// inclusive
var allDates = Enumerable.Range(0, (endDate - startDate).Days + 1).Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i));

// exclusive
var allDates = Enumerable.Range(1, (endDate - startDate).Days).Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i));
```